# SQLite: Selecting multiple counts from one column

Tags: sql, sqlite, pivot

I am running a query with SQLite and am relatively new to this. Glance of my dataset:

```
  ColA       ColB 
 Atlanta     mild
 Atlanta    moderate
 Miami       high
 Houston    moderate
 Houston    moderate
 Miami       mild
 Atlanta    moderate
```

I want group the results by Col A and then show 3 more columns (mild, moderate, high) and their counts -- Here is what I'm looking for:

```
 ColA    mild    moderate    high
Atlanta   1        2          0
Houston   0        2          0
Miami     1        0          1
```

I know how I can select just one of the columns (say, mild), but not sure how to select the others. Thanks!

Comment: Now we know what you want. In order to  give some focus to the question, please explain what you tried, what you thought, how it failed, how much succeeded etc.

Comment: Please provide a tailored toy database, in the shape of a few lines of `create table ...` and `insert ...`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pivot with conditional aggregation:

```
select 
    colA,
    sum(case when ColB = 'mild' then 1 else 0 end) mild,
    sum(case when ColB = 'moderate' then 1 else 0 end) moderate,
    sum(case when ColB = 'high' then 1 else 0 end) high
from mytable
group by colA
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=b37e38b33b741ac91f9c78b421568a4a)**:

```
ColA    | mild | moderate | high
:------ | :--- | :------- | :---
Atlanta | 1    | 2        | 0   
Houston | 0    | 2        | 0   
Miami   | 1    | 0        | 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Sqlite 3.30 added support for `FILTER` clauses to aggregate functions. When available I think it makes for a cleaner, easier to understand query than the `CASE` you have to use in older versions (In particular, you can use `count()` instead of `sum()` which better conveys what you're actually trying to calculate).

```
SELECT ColA
     , count(ColB) FILTER (WHERE ColB = 'mild') AS Mild
     , count(ColB) FILTER (WHERE ColB = 'moderate') AS Moderate
     , count(ColB) FILTER (WHERE ColB = 'high') AS High
FROM cities
GROUP BY ColA
ORDER BY ColA;
```

```
ColA        Mild        Moderate    High      
----------  ----------  ----------  ----------
Atlanta     1           2           0         
Houston     0           2           0         
Miami       1           0           1
```